# Identifying a white crispy garnish to a pork dish

Tags: pork

We went to an excellent restaurant last night and one of us was served pork with an unfamiliar, edible garnish;

[image: what's the white crispy thing?]

It was a crispy, long, white item which may have been a little salty and a little meaty, although I'm not sure.

Can anyone identify the White item on this plate?

Comment: Meaty?? Hmm, my first thought was a fried noodle of some kind. Did it taste of the sea at all?

Comment: Apparently salty, but it wasn't me eating it, so I don't know too much. I get the impression it was an alternative to pork crackling.

Comment: But sooo white! What ethnicity was the specialty of the restaurant?

Comment: It was a British restaurant, entirely modern European. There's a menu on their website but it doesn't include this particular dish -- http://www.middlethorpe.com/static/hhh_middlethorpe/uploads/documents/menus/dinner-menus-gourmet-a-la-carte-seasonal.doc

Comment: A version of [krupuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krupuk) perhaps? The prawn crackers im most asian places here are very white.

Comment: Hmmmm! I was about to go to sleep! Now I'm in a Google vortex! :)

Comment: Was it a bit like splinter-ish dried foam? It certainly *looks* like the prawn crackers here, only in another shape.

Comment: It was certainly very crispy, but with maybe a little bit of flexibility. I think it may be something like the prawn crackers / krupuk mentioned, actually!

Comment: As OP said little meaty, I would say it might be fried pork skin, also called pork rind. It looks similarly textured, the only difference is that pork rind is usually light brown in color, but this is white.

If this is a fancy restaurant, I can totally imgine them bleaching the skin somehow to create a white color and be a nice color contrast for the dish.

here is a stock photo:
http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-crispy-pork-pork-rind-white-background-isolate-image59494022

Comment: Definitely pork skin. Had it on our menu once. Massive hassle to make mind you.

Comment: @Doug why is it so white? Like Ron, I would expect it to be coloured with cooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't got time to make a real answer but here's a recipe http://m.cookingchanneltv.com/recipes/pork-rinds-chicharron.html

The reason it's white is all to-do with light diffusion and the fact the brown 1mm thick crisp pork skin has just been stretched to over 1cm thick.

Think... blowing up a balloon, it get lighter in colour as it gets bigger.